# Trying to compare the two arrays and print the line of the first array if they match and loop it for the entire first array

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code I have currently, but it just won't work, looking for some help if to complete this piece of coursework. Thanks in advance!

```
private static void reserveSeat() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner newFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\sylve\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\seats2.txt"));
    int index = 0;      

    while (newFile.hasNext()) {
        String seatsData = newFile.nextLine();
        String[] seatData = seatsData.split(" ");
        String seatNumber = seatData[0];
        String seatClass = seatData[1];
        boolean isWindow = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[2]);
        boolean isAisle = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[3]);
        boolean isTable = Boolean.parseBoolean(seatData[4]);
        double seatPrice = Double.parseDouble(seatData[5]);
        String email = seatData[6];

        seats[index] = new seatBookingSystem(seatNumber , seatClass , isWindow , isAisle , isTable , seatPrice , email);
        index++;

    }
    newFile.close();

    System.out.println("Would you like a STD or a 1st seat? ");
    String classWanted = input.next().toUpperCase();

    System.out.println("would you like a Aisle or a window? ");
    String typeWanted = input.next().toUpperCase();
    boolean inputWindow = typeWanted.equals("WINDOW");

    System.out.println("Would you like a table seat, Yes or No? ");
    String tableWanted = input.next().toUpperCase();
    boolean inputTable = tableWanted.equals("YES");

    Object[] results = new Object[] {null, classWanted, inputWindow, null, inputTable, null, null};

    if (seats[index] == results[0]) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(seats));
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("-- Sorry there are no seats avilable! Please try again! --");
```

I have tried searching pretty much everything I can think about and tried to use it but I cannot figure it out.

the file im reading in and the format is; seatNum seatClass isWindow isAisle isTable seatPrice eMail.

```
1A STD true false false 23.50 free
1B STD false true false 23.50 free
1D STD true true false 27.50 free
2A STD true false true 24.50 free
2B STD false true true 24.50 free
2D STD true true true 28.50 free
3A STD true false true 24.50 free
3B STD false true true 24.50 free
3D STD true true true 28.50 free
4A STD true false false 23.50 free
4B STD false true false 23.50 free
4D STD true true false 27.50 free
5A 1ST true true true 48.50 free
5C 1ST false true true 44.50 free
5D 1ST true false true 44.50 free
6A 1ST true true true 48.50 free
6C 1ST false true true 44.50 free
6D 1ST true false true 44.50 free
```

Comment: what is the expected output, and what output do you have instead? also, can you provide the input files?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is allow the user to search for the seats they want. So I want to filter the array and print the ones that match. The output I currently get is it just prints the full array and ill edit the post to show you the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's move one step back from the code you wrote and see what you want to do:

1. Parse a list of available seats from a text file, where each line is one seat and the seat properties are listes as values separated by spaces
2. Ask the user about the properties he desires
3. Loop over the list of seats and find those that match the user's criteria
4. Print the properties of the seats matching

Now look at what your code does:

1. You do a decent job of using a `while` loop to read the file line-by-line, use `string.Split` and some `parse` methods to explode the line into the desired values, and then organize each seat in an array (that is declared somewhere else, but I assume that part is still working as long as the array is big enough; I'd recommend to use a local `ArrayList<seatBookingSystem>` variable though).
2. You do a decent job of asking the user (although usability-wise it makes sense to give better instructions on what to enter, and making sure that e. g. if the input is not "WINDOW" it actually is "AISLE", etc.; but let's ignore that for now)

But now comes the part where things go wrong: you put the user's criteria in an `Object` array. Let's look at what you have now:

```
seats:
  type: seatBookingSystem[]
  length: 18
  entries:
     0: seatBookingSystem
     1: seatBookingSystem
     2: seatBookingSystem
        ...
    17: seatBookingSystem

results:
  type: Object[]
  length: 7
  entries:
    0: <null>
    1: String as Object
    2: boolean auto-boxed in Boolean as Object
    3: <null>
    4: boolean auto-boxed in Boolean as Object
    5: <null>
    6: <null>
```

As you can see, `results` is a list of properties, while `seats` is a list of seats *with* properties. Organizing the various variables in an array of `Object` and thereby losing type-safety does not have any benefits. Therefore, I'd do away with the `results` array altogether and stick to the local variables you already have. If you really insist on organizing all properties in one object, either create a strongly typed container class (like your `seatBookingSystem`), or use `seatBookingSystem` itself and provide dummy values for the values you don't care about.

In the end, you will need a second loop. This is the crucial part you're currently missing out on. You had the first loop to populate the array, now you need a second loop to iterate over that populated array and find the ones that match. You can do that with a `for` loop that increments an index variable of the element you are currently checking

```
for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
   seatBookingSystem current = seats[i];
   // TODO: expand expression to test for the other properties
   if (current.getSeatClass().equals(classWanted)) {
     System.out.println("Matching seat: " + current.getSeatNumber() + ", " +
         "Price: " + current.getSeatPrice());
   }
}
```

or use a `for-each` loop

```
for(seatBookingSystem current : seats) {
  // if ( ...
}
```

For the `for-each` loop to work, you'll have to make sure your array is properly dimensioned though. It currently seems to have a fixed size, so when there were less lines in the file than your `seats` array is long, you'll get some `null` values for the empty slots at the end of the array. That's where the aforementioned `ArrayList<seatBookingSystem>` would come in handy, that is always automatically resized properly according to the number of elements it currently holds.

Comment: Thanks for the help and overall feedback on my code, it really helped and it got this part of the program working!